# When "is" a congruence an object?

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

Three different situations:

1. Take a group $G$. If you have a *normal subgroup* $H$, you can form a quotient $G/H$.
2. (Can be considered as a corollary of 1.) Take an $R$-module $M$. If you have a *submodule* $N$, you can form a quotient $M/N$.
3. Take a topological space $X$. If you have a subspace $U$, you can form a quotient space $X/U$.

However, if you take a (commutative and unital) ring, you need to quotient by an *ideal*, that (except for the trivial case in which it contains 1) is *not* a subring.

In general the construction of a quotient object in a given category requires the notion of a [congruence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence), that is very different from a subobject. My question is

> How typical is that we can go from a subobject (maybe requiring an additional property) to a congruence?

or more precisely

> Is there a categorical notion encompassing this behaviour?

Edit:

(Based on comments by Rob Arthan and GEdgar). First two examples are *effective congruences* ([Definition 1.5](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence#EffectiveCongruence) in the link above). In other words we take two identical maps $f\colon A\to B$ and find a pullback $K$ with two maps $K\to A$. It can be treated as a *subobject of $A\times A$.*

But we want $K$ to be a subobject of $A$, so we could "replace $a\sim b$ by $ab^{-1}\in K$".

Comment: An ideal is always a subring.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I assume rings to be unital and commutative. I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you are making between rings and groups: in both cases a subthing won't give you a quotient thing in general, but special kind of subthings do: normal groups and ideals rather than arbitrary submodules of the ring viewed as a module over itself.

Comment: Indeed, subobjects and quotient objects are very different things, even in most concrete categories.

Comment: @RobArthan I think this is resolved by the "maybe requiring an additional property" clause: a "nice" subobject of a group (namely, a *normal* subgroup) yields a quotient, but an ideal in a ring is (almost) *never* a subobject (as long as rings are unital anyways). The point is that "subthing" in the group case means "special subobject" while in the ring case the "subthings" are not subobjects at all, except in the trivial case.

Comment: @RobArthan This is a very good comment. The logic behind this is: take a group. Take a subgroup. Check if it selects a mild condition (being normal). Then take a quotient.
For modules it automatically works (modules are abelian groups and each subgroup is normal. And ring action fortunately works as well).
For a ring you need a subring that is an ideal. The only one such that is the whole ring. (At least assuming conventions that rings are unital and commutative).

Comment: For topological spaces, the case where the quotient object is obtained by collapsing a subspace to a point is very special. You can form the quotient topology with respect to an arbitrary equivalence relation. Quotients by group actions are an important case.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I agree – _not all sensible quotients can be formed in this manner_. First I would like to characterize subobjects for which making a quotient makes sense (i.e. we can define an internal equivalence). The question when these _give all sensible quotients_ seems to be more difficult.

Comment: I think the main motivating examples here are in algebraic settings, where you can use an algebraic operation to represent a congruence $a \simeq b$ by an assertion $f(a, b) \in K$ for some algebraic term $f(a, b)$ (like $ab^{-1}$ in a group or $a - b$ in a module over a ring) and some subalgebra $K$. If there has been a general study of this kind of phenomenon, I think it is more likely to have been in universal algebra rather than in category theory.

Comment: Agree – I was thinking about posing this as a universal algebra question but then topological spaces came to my mind. 
I've added the tag.

Comment: The question is: characterize what is the kernel of a homomorphism.  Subring is not.  Subgroup (non-normal) is not.

Comment: I just note that both your examples can be constructed as the pushout of some $A→B$ and $A→∗$ where $A$ is a subobject of $B$ and $∗$ is the terminal object. But this does not work when $A=∅$ in the case of topological spaces. How much more general than this do you want to have?

Comment: @GEdgar Excellent observation. I'd put this as: in a category in which kernels are defined, all kernels can be turned into internal equivalences.

Comment: @Idéophage This is a great observation. A quotient object is generally defined as a coequalizer, but your pushout construction (with a terminal morphism) seems to be the right ingredient to treat a kernel pair as a subobject of $A$ instead of $A\times A$, as in the edit. (However, I need to think more about this)

Comment: So you may be interested in the concept of [abelian category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category). In these categories, there is a correspondence between subobjects and quotients: we have a notion of zero morphism between any two objects and we take the coequalizer of a subobject with this zero morphism to get the "cokernel". But there is a theorem (Mitchell's embedding theorem) that says that essentially, the only abelian categories are sub-categories of categories of $R$-modules. Maybe you can look at [semi-abelian categorie](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category)?

Comment: You are asking when you can “code” a congruence (which is an equivalence relation that is a subalgebra of the square) as a substructure of a single object or, perhaps, as the equivalence class of (the image of) a nullary operator (you can code ideals in not-necessarily-unital-rings that way, as well as normal subgroups, but not congruences in semigroups). I’m sure I recently saw someone talking about this property either here or in math.overflow...

Comment: Certainly categories in which *every* congruence arises by taking the quotient of a "normal subobject" are well-understood: they are called (pointed) protomodular categories and groups are the archetypal example. For the $X/A$ examples, I think it suffices to reproduce what's nice about these examples to assume that in your category, if $A/B$ is terminal, then $B=A$; so there exists no nontrivial "dense" subobjects, though that's not the usual meaning of "dense subobject." This is true in abelian categories, and I think in any regular category, but I'm not perfectly sure of that.